# Setting different batch size for training and validation using Tensorflow's tf.data API

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am migrating from the older queue-based data pipeline to the newer `tf.data` API. Suppose I have a code like the following, how can I explicitly set different batch sizes for my training and validation iterators.

```
filenames = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(...)  # Parse the record into tensors.
dataset = dataset.repeat()  # Repeat the input indefinitely.
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()



# Initialize `iterator` with training data.
training_filenames = ["/var/data/file1.tfrecord", 
"/var/data/file2.tfrecord"]
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={filenames: 
training_filenames})

# Initialize `iterator` with validation data.
validation_filenames = ["/var/data/validation1.tfrecord", ...]
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={filenames: 
validation_filenames})
```

EDIT:

Thank you. Based on the reply, my implementation is as follows:
 My implementation is like follows, but I'm not able to figure out why I'm getting this error:

```
import tensorflow as tf


def _parse(filename, label):
  image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
  image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
  image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [224, 224])
  image_resized.set_shape([224,224,3])
  return image_resized, label


def input_pipeline(imglist,labellist, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((imglist, labellist))
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse)  # Parse the record into tensors.
    dataset = dataset.repeat()  # Repeat the input indefinitely.
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset


imglist = glob.glob('/var/temp/*.jpg')
train_imgs=imglist[0:100]
train_labels = [i for i in range(100)]

val_imgs=imglist[200:250]
val_labels = [i for i in range(50)]
training_batch_size = 4

validation_batch_size = 1

training_ds = input_pipeline(train_imgs, train_labels, training_batch_size)
validation_ds = input_pipeline(val_imgs, val_labels, validation_batch_size)

handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
            handle, training_ds.output_types, training_ds.output_shapes)
input_batch = iterator.get_next()

train_iter = training_ds.make_initializable_iterator()
val_iter = validation_ds.make_initializable_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

     # Define training and validation handlers
    training_handle = sess.run(train_iter.string_handle())
    validation_handle = sess.run(val_iter.string_handle())

    # Initialize training and validation dataset
    sess.run(train_iter)
    sess.run(val_iter)


    # If we use training_handle, then input_batch tensor comes from training tfrecords
    training_batch = sess.run(input_batch, feed_dict={handle: training_handle})

    # If we use validation_handle, then input_batch tensor comes from validation tfrecords
    validation_batch = sess.run(input_batch, feed_dict={handle: validation_handle})
```

But I end up getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __init__(self, fetches, contraction_fn)
    281         self._unique_fetches.append(ops.get_default_graph().as_graph_element(
--> 282             fetch, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=True))
    283       except TypeError as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in as_graph_element(self, obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3589     with self._lock:
-> 3590       return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3591 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _as_graph_element_locked(self, obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3678       raise TypeError("Can not convert a %s into a %s." % (type(obj).__name__,
-> 3679                                                            types_str))
   3680 

TypeError: Can not convert a Iterator into a Tensor or Operation.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-50c4f3464d03> in <module>()
     47 
     48     # Initialize training and validation dataset
---> 49     sess.run(train_iter)
     50     sess.run(val_iter)
     51 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1118     # Create a fetch handler to take care of the structure of fetches.
   1119     fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(
-> 1120         self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
   1121 
   1122     # Run request and get response.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __init__(self, graph, fetches, feeds, feed_handles)
    425     """
    426     with graph.as_default():
--> 427       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
    428     self._fetches = []
    429     self._targets = []

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
    251         if isinstance(fetch, tensor_type):
    252           fetches, contraction_fn = fetch_fn(fetch)
--> 253           return _ElementFetchMapper(fetches, contraction_fn)
    254     # Did not find anything.
    255     raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r' % (fetch,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __init__(self, fetches, contraction_fn)
    284         raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r, '
    285                         'must be a string or Tensor. (%s)' %
--> 286                         (fetch, type(fetch), str(e)))
    287       except ValueError as e:
    288         raise ValueError('Fetch argument %r cannot be interpreted as a '

TypeError: Fetch argument <tensorflow.python.data.ops.iterator_ops.Iterator object at 0x7fa2c0697c88> has invalid type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.iterator_ops.Iterator'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a Iterator into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight modification needed to get the right answer:

```
import tensorflow as tf

imglist = glob.glob('/var/temp/*.jpg')
train_imgs=imglist[0:100]
train_labels = [i for i in range(100)]

val_imgs=imglist[200:250]
val_labels = [i for i in range(50)]

training_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_imgs,train_labels)).batch(4)
validation_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_imgs,val_labels)).batch(1)

handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
            handle, training_ds.output_types, training_ds.output_shapes)
input_batch = iterator.get_next()

train_iter = training_ds.make_initializable_iterator()
val_iter = validation_ds.make_initializable_iterator()



with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


     # Define training and validation handlers
    training_handle = sess.run(train_iter.string_handle())
    validation_handle = sess.run(val_iter.string_handle())



    sess.run(train_iter.initializer)
    # If we use training_handle, then input_batch tensor comes from training tfrecords
    training_batch = sess.run(input_batch, feed_dict={handle: training_handle})
    print("Training...")
    print(training_batch)

    sess.run(val_iter.initializer)
    # If we use validation_handle, then input_batch tensor comes from validation tfrecords
    print("Validation")
    validation_batch = sess.run(input_batch, feed_dict={handle: validation_handle})
    print(validation_batch)
```

Answer (score 7):

I would create 2 `tf.data.Dataset`, one for training and one for validation subsets. Once you have both datasets pipelines defined (where you are able to define 2 different batch sizes), you can join them in the graph by creating a single `tf.data.Iterator` with a handler (in my case, the `tf.placeholder` `handle`).

```
import tensorflow as tf


def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(...)  # Parse the record into tensors.
    dataset = dataset.repeat()  # Repeat the input indefinitely.
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset


training_filenames = ["/var/data/file1.tfrecord",
                      "/var/data/file2.tfrecord"]
training_batch_size = 32
validation_filenames = ["/var/data/validation1.tfrecord",
                        "/var/data/validation2.tfrecord"]
validation_batch_size = 16

training_ds = input_pipeline(training_filenames, training_batch_size)
validation_ds = input_pipeline(validation_filenames, validation_batch_size)

handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
            handle, training_ds.output_types, training_ds.output_shapes)
input_batch = iterator.get_next()
```

Before requesting batches from any of both datasets, you can get correponding handlers from each dataset using `string_handle()`. After that, when you run `input_batch`, you can decide if it comes from training or validation by defining it on the `handle` placeholder.

```
train_iter = training_ds.make_initializable_iterator()
val_iter = validation_ds.make_initializable_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Define training and validation handlers
    training_handle = sess.run(train_iter.string_handle())
    validation_handle = sess.run(val_iter.string_handle())

    # Initialize training and validation dataset
    sess.run(train_iter.initializer)
    sess.run(val_iter.initializer)

    # If we use training_handle, then input_batch tensor comes from training tfrecords
    trainaing_batch = sess.run(input_batch, feed_dict={handle: training_handle})

    # If we use validation_handle, then input_batch tensor comes from validation tfrecords
    validation_batch = sess.run(input_batch, feed_dict={handle: validation_handle})
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT:
Your current error seems to be due to trying to do a `sess.run()` on a `tf.data.Iterator`. Try to replace `sess.run(train_iter)` for `sess.run(train_iter.initializer)` (and same for validation iterator). `train_iter.initializer` is the `tf.Operation` that initializes `train_iter` iterator. Everything should work now.

Comment: Pls check my response.  Doesn't seem to work with my implementation.

Comment: Hello @user1050648! I just saw right now your question edit. I'm quite confused with it, are you feeding data from tfrecords or directly from images? Your first question suggests that you are feeding data from tfrecords, but your last edit suggests that you feed data from images in a directory.

Comment: I missed to add `.initializer` on `sess.run(train_iter.initializer)` and `sess.run(val_iter.initializer)`. It was probably the source of your error (also in the second version of the code). @user1050648, can you check if it works now?